# How can I pass a multi dimensional array as an argument to a worker thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How can I do this in c#?  I have GUI and worker threads and I have to pass the array or be able to access the array from worker array?!

```
Thread t = new Thread (delegate() { DoWork (double[,] data); });
t.Start();


static void DoWork (double[,] data) { do some work...; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        Work threadWork = new Work(yourdata);
        Thread newThread = 
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadWork.DoWork));
        newThread.Start();
    }
}

class Work 
{
    private double[,] myData;
    public Work(double[,] data) {
        myData = data;
    }

    public void DoWork() { /* use myData */ }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a parameterised thread delegate (ParameterisedThreadStart):

```
Thread t = new Thread(o =>
  {
    double[,] data = (double[,])o;
    DoWork(data);
  });

t.Start(myData);
```

**EDIT:** or as Paul suggests in comments, capture myData via a closure:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => DoWork(myData));
t.Start();
```

Comment: How is this better that just passing in a method (to ThreadStart ) to a class that contains the data?

Comment: Good point, if he only ever wants to call it on the myData local, capturing the data in a closure would also work: Thread t = new Thread(() => DoWork(myData));

Answer (score 1):

All thread delegates accept an object. Pass the array and then cast in the worker:

```
double[,] myarray = ...;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state=>{
  double[,] arrayArg = (double[,])state;
  DoWork(arrayArg);
}, myarray);
```

ThreadStart has similar argument. Make sure you do no touch the array in UI thread while is under the worker control...